# How to stop vim from defaulting to older version?

Tags: linux, vim, editor

I have the latest version of vim installed in my home dir (I'm a user on a shared environment), with all my customizations and stuff. I've set `alias vim=$HOME/path_to_vim_dir`, in my `.zshrc` file. I've also set `EDITOR=vim`, `SVN_EDITOR=vim`. However, anytime I do a commit operation without `-m "..."` in either git or svn, or even when editing `crontab`, the version of vim that opens up is an old version somewhere in `/usr/share/`... how do I stop this and get vim (no matter which program calls it) to default to my version? I've also tried setting `EDITOR=$HOME/path_to_vim_dir/bin/vim`, but that has no effect either.

Comment: @n00b32: vim related questions [are on-topic on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su). even when it is offtopic, don't comment about it, but flag as offtopic and suggest a better site in the presented dialog.

Comment: vim related as in related to USING vim not configurating/installing it. so some1 can ask "how do i install php on debian" on SO ? it is php related... but true ill use the offtopic dialog. i commented instead because its not that big of an offtopic, just a guideline for future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about zsh, but I know in bash you have to export the variables `EDITOR` or `SVN_EDITOR`.  Simply setting them doesn't do the trick.

Also, set it to the absolute path of the binary (path_to_your_home/path_to_vim_dir/vim).

Comment: i do export it, however that doesn't work. it's not that crontab/svn is using the wrong editor. for e.g., if i set EDITOR to emacs or gedit, it opens what ever is set. It opens vi too, but from /bin/vi instead of $HOME/path... 

it looks as if when I invoke crontab or svn ci, the editor is called by a different process that doesn't see my path (probably the script that calls it was written in a different shell).

Comment: @user564376 Did you try setting EXPORT with the absolute path of the binary, without using variables such as $HOME?  (so /home/user564376/local/bin/vim for example.)

Comment: So I figured out the reason. Although I had set vi to default to my version, the call to vi by svn/git/crontab is made from a script written in sh. Since I don't use that shell, it defaults to /bin/sh. You're right that setting export to the path of the binary helped, but the LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to be set for it to open. This is set in my shell (zsh), but when a call is made from /bin/sh in the script, this variable is unset and i get an error. Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: @user564376 I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I've reached the end of my knowledge.  You might want to consider asking on http://unix.stackexchange.com/  you might get a better answer than I was able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your vim location is on your $PATH, ahead of the location where it is installed system-wide.

Comment: @user564376 that only addresses half of this answer.  You need to have `$HOME/path_to_vim_dir` ahead of `/usr/bin/` or the system will never find your version.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mention that it is located ahead of /usr/bin and all other system directories.